# how to chain field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This my engine models

```
from django.db import models

class Colors(models.Model):
   color_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.color_name
```

This my Cars models

```
from django.db import models

class Cars(models.Model):
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    car_colors = models.ManytoManyField(Colors, related_name='Car Colors')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.car_model
```

O.K. Let's see my CarsData Model.

This my CarsData models

```
from django.db import models

class CarsData(models.Model):
    car_barcode= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    available_color = ChainedForeignKey(
                   Cars,
                   chained_field="car_model",
                   chained_model_field="car_colors",
                   show_all=False,
                   auto_choose=True
                 )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.car_barcode
```

My admin.py looks like that:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from myapp.models import *

class CarsDataAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CarsData

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(CarsDataAdminForm, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        self.fields['available_color'].choices = [(csc.id,csc.car_colors) for csc in Cars.objects.all()


class CarsDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CarsDataAdminForm

admin.site.register(CarsData,CarsDataAdmin)
```

Is there anyway to show in the ChoiceField 'just' color_name field datas? I see just car_model because i have to set it :

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.car_model
```

How can i chain available_colors field to color_name field? I want to show in available_colors choices just color names like red, blue, black, white...

Can you please give me an example?

Comment: What is `ChainedForeignKey`? Where does it come from? What does it do?

Comment: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't get your code:

```
class CarsData(models.Model):

    car_barcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    available_color = ChainedForeignKey(
        Cars,
        chained_field="car_model", # should be a field in THIS model
        chained_model_field="car_colors", # should be the matching field 
                                          # in the Cars model
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True
    )
```

And both referenced fields must be ForeignKeys to the same (third) model.

Maybe this works, even without changing the AdminForm (I also changed the model names to singular and remove some repetitions, as the most common use dictates):

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class CarModel(models.Model):

    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    available_colors = models.ManytoManyField(Color, through='AvailableColor')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.model

class AvailableColor(models.Model):

    car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.color)


class CarData(models.Model):

    car_barcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)

    car_color = ChainedForeignKey(
        AvailableColor,
        chained_field="car_model", # field in CarData
        chained_model_field="car_model", # field in AvailableColor
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True
    )
```

You can't do otherwise because you need two models with a matching FK. Using `Cars.car_colors.through` (that is a valid model on which to query etc) you don't have a good display. With a (dummy) explicit intermediate model you define **unicode** and the admin should show the correct data.

Comment: Thanks!! Very simple and nice example.